# How to prevent REXML from changing encoding

Tags: ruby, xml, rexml

I'm trying to edit a xml file with Ruby and REXML but after writing the file back to disk the encoding is changed. But i need to keep the original encoding of the file!

This is what my xml looks before editing:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'AdHoc|iPhone' ">
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>..\Bin\iPhoneSimulator\AdHoc</OutputPath>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <MtouchUseSGen>false</MtouchUseSGen>
    <MtouchDebug>False</MtouchDebug>
    <CodesignKey>iPhone Developer:</CodesignKey>
    <MtouchUseLlvm>false</MtouchUseLlvm>
    <MtouchUseThumb>false</MtouchUseThumb>
    <MtouchArch>ARMv6</MtouchArch>
    <CodesignProvision>A2FBBCDB-218A-4CCC-88ED-A484AAE87EA5</CodesignProvision>
    <MtouchI18n />
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="monotouch" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.Json" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

and here after writing it back to disk:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=' &apos;$(Configuration)|$(Platform)&apos; == &apos;AdHoc|iPhone&apos; '>
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>..\Bin\iPhoneSimulator\AdHoc</OutputPath>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <MtouchUseSGen>false</MtouchUseSGen>
    <MtouchDebug>False</MtouchDebug>
    <CodesignKey>iPhone Developer:</CodesignKey>
    <MtouchUseLlvm>false</MtouchUseLlvm>
    <MtouchUseThumb>false</MtouchUseThumb>
    <MtouchArch>ARMv6</MtouchArch>
    <CodesignProvision>A2FBBCDB-218A-4CCC-88ED-A484AAE87EA5</CodesignProvision>
    <MtouchI18n/>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include='System'/>
    <Reference Include='System.Xml'/>
    <Reference Include='System.Core'/>
    <Reference Include='monotouch'/>
    <Reference Include='System.Xml.Linq'/>
    <Reference Include='System.Web.Services'/>
    <Reference Include='System.Json'/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Here is my code:

```
File.open('file.xml') do |config_file|
 # Open the document and edit the file
 config = Document.new(config_file)
 config.root.elements['PropertyGroup'].elements['CodesignKey'].text = 'my new developer'

 # Write the result to a new file.
 formatter = REXML::Formatters::Default.new
 File.open('file.xml', 'w') do |result|
  formatter.write(config, result)
 end
end
```

Comment: Do you know which is the original encoding? From the text that looks like character encoding for html...

Comment: TextWrangler says: Unicode(UTF-8,no BOM)

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927507/ruby-convert-single-quotes-to-double-quotes-in-xml). Set the attribute delimiter character after initializing Document object.

```
config = Document.new(config_file)
config.context[:attribute_quote] = :quote
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not really related with the original encoding. You can see that your strings were replaced with html escaping characters. **"** was replaced with **'** and **'** with **'**

Instead of REXML, you can try the Nokogiri gem

A basic code looks like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

filename = "file.xml"
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.new(filename))

# Check the node content
doc.root.xpath("//MtouchArch").text

# do your processing
# ...

doc.to_xml
```